# Getting Intent data regardless of status of receiving activity

Tags: java, android

I have a an activity that sends data to another in the usual android way (by using putExtras)

```
i.putExtra("ID_NUMBER", id);
```

But I have an activity that can be either closed or in the background when this intent is sent. I am using the following method to catch the intent when my activity is in the background:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("ID_NUMBER");
}
```

But I've noticed this method does not get called when the activity is created. Is there a catch all method that intents pass through when entering an activity or is the standard way of doing this to get the Intent in OnCreate()?

Comment: I think you need to read documentation, on intent will never called when your activity is in background. So your method will never call.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki I think, that YOU need to read the docu, as the `onNewIntent` is called independently on the fact, if the activity is in the background or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the code to react on new intent and put it also into `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    doOnNewIntent( getIntent() );
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    doOnNewIntent( intent );
}

private void doOnNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String id = intent.getStringExtra("ID_NUMBER");
}
```